# How to get the size of a table in parse, and order id number?

Tags: parse-platform

I have very large table in parse.
Let say it looks like this

```
   A        B       C
1. val_A_1  val_B_1 val_c
2. val_A_2  val_B_2 val_c
3. val_A_3  val_B_3 val_c
4. val_A_4  val_B_4 val_c
...
1000000. val_A_1000000  val_B_1000000 val_c


        ParseQuery<MyClass> query = ParseQuery
                .getQuery(MyClass.class);
        query.whereEqualTo("C", "val_c");
```

my query is the above one. I know that this one will return a result, and I can do this
objects.size() command to get the size. but in this case I would need to take all objects :( .
What if I got 1 000 000 records , how long it would take ?

is there any other faster solution ?

one more thing, when I got the result from some query that is searching only where the B have value "val_B_3"

```
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<MyClass>() {
            public void done(List<MyClass> objects, ParseException e) {
```

How can I know the val_B_3 it is at the position 3 ?

Comment: Do you want the max value of the column or size of all the objects??

Comment: I dont think there is any way of knowing if val_B_3 is at position 3....unless in DB you add a incremental number like position to track its position. Then you can just get the row and 'position' will be give you where it belongs.